# get query's query string

Tags: wp-query, query-posts

By the time index.php runs, it seems as though there is already a query populated.

How can I find out what that query's query string is?

eg. `new WP_Query([query string is here])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at `global $query_string;`.

Or `var_dump( $GLOBALS['wp_query'] );`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php var_dump( $GLOBALS['wp_query'] ); ?>
```

and if you have custom loop in your template, dont forget to use (query_post()) `<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>` or (new WP_Query) `<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>`
:)

Function should be called after The Loop to ensure conditional tags work as expected.

Comment: Please use `get_posts()` for that.